# How to save axios GET response data as json or as same as the arrived response

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

```
export class LoadProfile extends Component {
    state = {
    data: ''
   }

componentDidMount() {
    axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/profile/all',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'json',
      }).then((response) => {
        // here I can iterate all response data.
        response.data.forEach((d) => {
           console.log("d: "+d.displayName)
        });
        // here I am setting sate. Later I can't iterate this data any more 
        this.setState(response.data);
      });

   }
 }
```

Later at render method when I tried as follows:

```
this.state.data.forEach((el) => {
    console.log("el: "+el.displayName)
})
```

I got error as  TypeError: this.state.data.forEach is not a function

In this case, it was a JSON format. How can I save the response as it came from the server or save in JSON object so that I can iterate later?

Updated question with full code:-

```
export class LoadProfile extends Component {

state = {
    data: ''
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080//profile/all',
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'json',
      }).then((response) => {

        this.setState({data: response.data});

        response.data.forEach((d) => {
           console.log("d: "+d.displayName)
        });
        // this is fine
        this.state.data.forEach((e) => {
           console.log("e: "+e.displayName) 
        });
      });
}

render() {
    return (
    <Table singleLine>
    <Table.Header>
      <Table.Row>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Id</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Fullname</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Birth Date</Table.HeaderCell>
        <Table.HeaderCell>Gender</Table.HeaderCell>
      </Table.Row>
    </Table.Header>

    <Table.Body>
       // Here error: TypeError: this.state.data.forEach is not a function
      {this.state.data.forEach((el) => {
        return (
          <Table.Row key={el.id}>
            <Table.Cell>{el.id}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              {el.displayName}
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{el.birthDate}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{el.gender}</Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        );
      })
      }
    </Table.Body> 
  </Table>

    )
}
 }

 export default LoadProfile
```

So I can iterate only inside axios response method. But I can't iterate in the render method. What is wrong?

Comment: The default value of `data` is an empty string, which doesn't make much sense if it's going to be an array. You could use an empty array as a default value `state = { data: [[] }` or just `null` and check before using it `this.state.data && this.state.data.map(/**/)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a key for the state:

```
 this.setState({ data: response.data });
```

You should also set the initial state as an empty array so that the initial render can find the map function (use map, not forEach, forEach does not do anything with the return value):

```
  state = {
    data: []
   }
```

```
this.state.data.map((el) => {
        return (
          <Table.Row key={el.id}>
            <Table.Cell>{el.id}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>
              {el.displayName}
            </Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{el.birthDate}</Table.Cell>
            <Table.Cell>{el.gender}</Table.Cell>
          </Table.Row>
        );
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

do this instead

```
this.setState({data: response.data});
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.